# Java Scanner by page

Tags: java

I have a general question: is it possible in Java to read in a document e.g. by using a Scanner object and to locate/identify the page in which a word occurs?

maybe something similar to `next()`, `hasNextLine()`

**[EDIT]**

document = Word document

Comment: What kind of document and what is the "page"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sort of document are you trying to read? Simple text files (which is what `Scanner` is designed for) don't generally have the concept of pages. You can't use `Scanner` for things like PDF and Word documents.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. yes indeed i was thinking of Word docs. would Console class be a solution? Can Java read Word docs at all?

Comment: @Baba Which part of the JavaDocs for [Console](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) leads you to believe it would be good for determining the 'page number' of a word in a Word document?  BTW - one common API for dealing with MS docs, is [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).  Although I have not used it, reports from others suggest it's support for MS documents is 'patchy'.

Comment: +1 for Apache POI - also suited for other MS Office formats like Excel spreadsheets.